# Is ORDER BY stable for several rows with the same key values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Supposing I have a table `friends` like:

```
name   | age
-------+----
Xi     | 60
Joel   | 34
Kanna  | 10000
Gawr   | 10000
```

and I make something like `SELECT * FROM friends ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1` and the result will be `Kanna, 10000`. But there is another candidate - Gawr. Is it correct to think that the result will be `Kanna, 10000` absolutely always (so, **the ordering is stable for rows with the same ordering key**)? Is it true for all RDBMS? If - just for some of them, is it true at least for Postgres?

Comment: unless you also order by a tiebreaker column, I don't believe you can guarantee the order.

Comment: I have the same intuition, but it's interesting that I always get the same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ORDER BY` logic should *always* be specific enough to sort the way you want.  So if you want Kanna's record to appear first in the limit query, you should add a descending sort level on the name:

```sql
SELECT * FROM friends ORDER BY age DESC, name DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Even if Postgres' sort appears to be stable with regard to a certain order, the behavior could change as the underlying data changes.  And also the behavior almost certainly varies across different databases.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` is not stable.  Period.

Why not?  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets (well, technically multi-sets because they can have duplicates).

Hence, there is no "default" ordering to fall back on.  In fact, running the same `ORDER BY` on the same data could result in different orderings.

As an example, the sorting might not even use any sophisticated algorithm; it might use an index.  The table could be reindexed -- and the ordering in the *index* could change, depending on the reindexing algorithm.

Sorting might "look" stable because it produces the same results.  However, with no default ordering, you really cannot call it stable in any database.  If you want a stable sort, include a unique key as the last key in the `ORDER BY` list.

Answer (score 1):

If it is stable in some case, that depends on the implementation. The implementor is not obligated to make the order of ties stable.

Even if it's stable in the current version of PostgreSQL for example, they would be free to change their code in the next release in some way that changes the default order, or makes it not stable from one invocation of the same query to the next invocation. They would not be violating any promise or standard by doing that.

So you should not rely on it being stable even from version to version of the same brand of RDBMS, nor between brands.